# Customers database structure

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I have two tables Orders and Owners which represent natural person owner of a order.In order tables I have a OwnerId column that make the conection.Now I want to add a legal entity type of Owner the problem is I need to add it as a new table and then be able to select the order and his owner (legal or natural) in only one query.What structure you think is the best that can allow me to do those things?

Comment: Add it as column in owner table instead of separate table

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a legal entity type of Owner

As you mention  this it looks like `legal entity type` should be added as a new column to `Owners` table which can hold the values like `legal` or `natural`

```
ALTER TABLE Owners ADD legal_entity_type VARCHAR(60);
```

Then you can do select for `legal_entity_type` of 'natural'

```
SELECT * FROM
Owners own
JOIN
Orders order
ON own.OwnerId =order.OwnerId AND own.legal_entity_type = 'natural'
```